# Can I make Ubuntu's windows frame edges rectangular and not rounded?

Tags: unity

I want to ask can I make Ubuntu's Windows edges rectangular like the Windows OS windows and not rounder like they are on default. I am running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: You could use another theme, like Numix (available in the `shimmer-themes` package I think). Then you use `unity-tweak-tool` to select that theme, which you can install from the Software Center.

Comment: Yes thank you for the advice, really liked Numix theme. Can i change the background color of the top frame of the window's(the tittle bar)? I want to make it more more brownish and lighter like the Ambiance theme.

Comment: I added an answer. As for customizing the theme, you can do that but it's not easy. It's probably easier to find another theme (maybe someone has customized the Numix theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use another theme, like Numix (available in the `shimmer-themes` package I think).
Then you use `unity-tweak-tool` to select that theme, which you can install from the Software Center.

The Numix theme is an example.
You can find a lot of GTK themes on the internet. After downloading a theme, create a folder named `.themes` in your home folder if it doesn't exist already (it will be a hidden folder) and extract the theme to there.